# prove that$x-\dfrac{\langle a,x\rangle}{\langle a,a\rangle}a$ is orthogonal to $a$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove that $x-\dfrac{\langle a,x\rangle}{\langle a,a\rangle}a$ is orthogonal to $a$.

I know this has something to do with the QR algorithm, but I am unsure of where to start.I started with QR decomposition and I am unsure of where to head next

Comment: You don't need the QR algorithm.  Just use the definition of orthogonality.  You'll prove it almost immediately.

Comment: Hint: the (real) inner product is linear in both of its arguments

Comment: oh, so I could try proving that matrix a times the first expression is equal to I?

Comment: That's not the definition of orthogonal vectors...

Comment: Here $a$ is evidently a vector belonging to the same inner product space as $x$, perhaps Euclidean $n$-space.

Comment: that the dot product of the vectors is zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that two vectors $v,w$ are orthogonal if $\langle v,w\rangle=0$. So, to prove that $v:=x-\frac{\langle x,a\rangle}{\langle a,a\rangle} a$ is orthogonal to $a$, we compute

$$\langle v,a\rangle  = \langle x-\frac{\langle x,a\rangle}{\langle a,a\rangle} a,a \rangle.$$

But, recall that the inner product is linear, so we have

$$\langle x-\frac{\langle x,a\rangle}{\langle a,a\rangle} a,a \rangle = \langle x, a \rangle - \frac{\langle x,a\rangle}{\langle a,a\rangle} \langle a,a\rangle = \langle x,a \rangle -\langle x,a\rangle = 0.$$